# Shell scripting extract specific terms from a line

Tags: shell

I'm a beginner in using shell scripting. I wanted to pull out a specific term from several lines that I have already excluded from a large text file (say, temporal lobe), and add the values that I have extracted together.

For example,

```
Line 1: 1    3    13579 586  Right-Temporal  72    73    66   54
Line 2: 2    5    24680 587  Left-Temporal   89    44    65   56
```

*The spaces between each terms are very wide, but I can't seem to separate the spaces...

Say if I want to add the number 10455+10475 together using shell scripting, what will be the example of the script that I can type in? I have searched for this question on internet using multiple sites, and none of it seems to be associated with what I am doing

Comment: Does the `10455+10475 ` have any connection to the two sample llnes? And going back to the example, what did you want to do with the example?

Comment: 10455 and 10475 each represent the volume of the region. So Right-temperal lobe is 10455 voxels in this case. I wanted to add all the regions' volume together to find the total volume, and cross check with other subjects of similar volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input text(added additional rows for better explanation)

```
Line 1: 1 3 13579 586 Right-Temporal 72 73 66 54
Line 2: 2 5 24680 587 Left-Temporal 89 44 65 56
Line 3: 2 5    24681 587 Left-Temporal 89 44 65 56
Line 4: 2 5        24682 587 Left-Temporal 89 44 65 56
```

For example, if you want to filter out `13579` & `24680` etc .. Which is 5th column with space as a delimiter, you can sum those values using below command

```
awk '{total += $5} END {print total}' TemporalLobe.txt
```

Note: Even if you have multiple space in-front of your text, it will be considered as single delimiter. For ex: I have added Line3 & Line 4. These two lines have additional spaces in-front of column 5. `awk`  treats additional spaces as a part of delimiter.

#### Edit 1:

Assuming that, 'Temporal' is the key to `grep`.

```
grep Temporal TemporalLobe.txt. | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'
```

similarly, you can apply this for multiple columns.

```
grep Temporal TemporalLobe.txt. | awk '{total += $3 + $4} END {print total}' 
result = 25
```

**Explanation:**

- grep will extract desired lines from large data file 'TemporalLobe.txt'.
- This data is passed to `awk` using | (pipe)
- awk will extract column3 ($3) , column4 ($4). It will sum both columns

i.e. `Result = ( {1 + 3} + {2 + 5} + {2 + 5} + {2 + 5})`

→    `Result = 25`

Comment: I believe that the lines are separated by tab as a delimiter. Does the tab work the same as space as well?

Comment: @GT_Dunk, did you mean all data is in single line & seperated by tab spaces ?? OR column 5 values separated by tab spaces?

Comment: @GT_Dunk, Above answer works even if the columns are separated by tab spaces. Try the command. Let us know the result.

Comment: for my example, each line was shown independently through using grep. So I basically used grep "Right-Temporal-Lobe" TemporalLobe.txt. And when I tried using the commands, it gave me a number way larger than the actual value. Is it because each lines were indenpendent of each other, instead of being together in one single file?

Comment: @GT_Dunk, We can include grep command as well. I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks @Raju, It worked out nicely! I added the path to my directory and your commands work like a charm. I greatly appreciate your help